# Django loop through list in two parts

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I do not understand how I can loop through a list in two goes. For example, display items 0-3, then 4-7.

In particular, the list "arr" is passed through the view, then I'm in the template trying to display the list.

I've trying a while loop, or slice etc, but just keep on getting errors.

arr contains 3 string values per iteration from the views

```
arr.append([title, link, img_url])
```

```
<div id="newsgrid">
  {% for article in arr %}
  <div class="card">
      <img src="{{ article.0 }}" alt="news image">
      <small><a href="{{ article.1 }}">Read more</a></small>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you please paste here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to paginate the view? Such as items 0-3 are on page 1, and 4-7 are on page 2. You can use Django's own [paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/pagination/) in that case. Or are you trying to display them on the same page, but on different sections. In that case, it does not make sense to me that they are on the same list. So you can split them on the backend and deliver to the frontend as seperate lists.

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding paginator. Ideally I want both. So show the first 8 results in a card format (headline, image and short paragraph), and then another 8 for example in a shorter headline only form. But they are from the same list of articles.

I will try to implement the pagination first, and then try to split to different sections.